# Dart event handlers and lambdas

Tags: html, lambda, event-handling, dart

I am confused by `Dart`'s lambdas. Take for instance this working example:

```dart
void main() {
    print("Hello Dart!");
}
```

Now if I change this to:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
    querySelector("#sample_text_id")
        ..onClick.listen((e) => fizz);
}

void fizz(MouseEvent mouseEvent, String s) {
    print("Hello $s!");
}
```

I **don't** get any syntax errors, even though I'm sending the `MouseEvent` to a (non0lambda) `fizz` method that takes 2 arguments!

1. Why am I not getting any compile/syntax errors?
2. How do I properly pass `onClick.listen(...)` the `fizz` method (in other words, no lambda)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you're not actually passing fizz as the event handler. You're anonymous function:

```dart
(e) => fizz
```

is what you're passing as the event handler. In this case e would be the event parameter that Listen expects and you're just discarding it. Then you return fizz (a function) which the listen doesn't use as it expect void. Remember that in dart functions are first class citizens and can be passed around and even assigned to variable.

To achieve what you want you would need something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  querySelector("#sample_text_id")
        ..onClick.listen(fizz);
}

void fizz(MouseEvent mouseEvent, String s) {
  print("Hello $s!");
}
```

Which should generate a warning as you're passing a function which expects too many parameters. This can also be fixed by making `String s` on your function optional:

```dart
void fizz(MouseEvent event, [String s = "World"]) {
  print("Hello $s");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your fizz has the expected signature (e.g. make s optional as Matt showed) you can pass the method directly without creating a lambda.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
    querySelector("#sample_text_id")
        .onClick.listen(fizz);
}

void fizz(MouseEvent mouseEvent, [String s]) {
    print("Hello $s!");
}
```

Hint: You don't need two dots before onClick when you don't chain more calls to the result of         `querySelector("#sample_text_id")`

Chaining example:

```dart
    querySelector("#sample_text_id")
        ..onClick.listen(fizz)
        ..onMouseOver.listen(fizz2);
```